# discard hidden file system with FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#

How to discard getting notified with files system: e.g: thumbs.db

I have this instance of `FileSystemWatcher`:

```
FileSystemWatcher watching = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
watching.Filter = "*.*";
watching.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
```

In a folder of 'watching', if an image is opened, a

> `thumbs.db`

file is generated. the program will get stuck with the file image. Off couse, I can discard that file in OnChanged but that is not elegant. How can I discard hidden or files system in the filter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can filter it out before receiving the event. In the OnChanged method you should probably look at the Attributes of the file and discard any that have the Hidden or maybe System flags set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no better way.
Googled for an answer and saw this answer from Microsoft MVP: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/3082b7a3-3499-455e-bf4f-20249ea0f87e